# How to get the full class name of a widget in the Android layout xml file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

For some reason, I want to get the full class name of a widget used in the layout file. Some are displayed by full class name like `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` while some default widgets are not.

For example, in the code below, `TextView` actually corresponds to `android.widget.TextView`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

All these widget type tags with abbreviated form in XML files come from `android.widget` package? Or in which files these dependencies determined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me begin by saying that you can't really be certain of the exact runtime type that a tag will result in merely by inspecting the layout. `LayoutInflater` is the (base) class that handles translating layouts to runtime `View` hierarchies, and its `Factory` interface "plugin" setup, along with Android's open inheritance component design, present several points where default layout inflation can be modified, or completely overridden. Furthermore, there is no technical requirement that any particular name produce any specific subtype of `View`.

However, you're probably safe to make some basic assumptions, in general – e.g., a `<Button>` tag will likely result in an instance of `android.widget.Button`, or a subclass thereof – because otherwise things could get nonsensical and broken pretty quick. Most often, these inflation modifications are made in order to enhance or extend the base UI types, rather than to wildly alter the standard procedures.

That said, on its own the platform inflater will look in the following four packages, in order, for any `View` name that does not contain a period (`.`), which is the sole criterion used to distinguish abbreviated class names from fully qualified ones:

- `android.widget`, where most of the available platform `View` classes are to be found.
- `android.webkit`, for `<WebView>`.
- `android.app`, for `<ActivityView>`, used only by the system and hidden from the SDK.
- `android.view`, for `<View>`, `<SurfaceView>`, `<TextureView>`, and a few more hidden ones.

Before that, though, it will have given first chance to create a `View` to (potentially) multiple `Factory` implementations, and it will not bother to look if any of those return one. If they don't, then the inflater will check the aforementioned packages, successively prepending each one to the abbreviated name, and attempting to load the result as a `View` subclass using the `Context`'s `ClassLoader`.

If the abbreviated name doesn't exist in any of those packages, you will eventually get a rethrown `ClassNotFoundException` (wrapped in an `InflateException`) with a message saying `Didn't find class "android.view.BadLayoutTagName"`, showing that `android.view` is indeed the last package checked.

---

Possibly the most common external `Factory` implementation these days comes from the AndroidX and Material Components libraries, and those both will substitute their own extended classes for a number of the platform `View`s, so you should at least be aware of this.

AndroidX's `Factory` delegates `View` creation to a helper class, `AppCompatViewInflater`, which makes the following substitutions:

| Tag name: | In package `androidx.appcompat.widget`: |
| --- | --- |
| `AutoCompleteTextView` | `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` |
| `Button` | `AppCompatButton` |
| `CheckBox` | `AppCompatCheckBox` |
| `CheckedTextView` | `AppCompatCheckedTextView` |
| `EditText` | `AppCompatEditText` |
| `ImageButton` | `AppCompatImageButton` |
| `ImageView` | `AppCompatImageView` |
| `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` | `AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView` |
| `RadioButton` | `AppCompatRadioButton` |
| `RatingBar` | `AppCompatRatingBar` |
| `SeekBar` | `AppCompatSeekBar` |
| `Spinner` | `AppCompatSpinner` |
| `TextView` | `AppCompatTextView` |
| `ToggleButton` | `AppCompatToggleButton` |

The Material Components library is built on AndroidX, and it further customizes `AppCompatViewInflater` with its own subclass, `MaterialComponentsViewInflater`, overriding a few of the above substitutions thusly:

| Tag name: | In package `com.google.android.material`: |
| --- | --- |
| `AutoCompleteTextView` | `textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` |
| `Button` | `button.MaterialButton` |
| `CheckBox` | `checkbox.MaterialCheckBox` |
| `RadioButton` | `radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton` |
| `TextView` | `textview.MaterialTextView` |

---

Lastly, I would mention that there are various other tags that are not for `View`s, and that would normally be consumed by `LayoutInflater` or a `Factory`. Since you're processing these layouts yourself, you may need to decide what these mean for your specific aims.

- `<include>`, for [reusing complete layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Include).
- `<merge>`, for [reusing layout "inners", without an enclosing parent](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge).
- `<requestFocus>`, for attempting to set the focus after layout.
- `<tag>`, for adding keyed tags to `View`s in layout XML (only on Lollipop and later versions).
- `<blink>`, an [Easter egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) that you likely won't ever see.
- `<fragment>`, actually handled by the `Activity` as its `LayoutInflater`'s private `Factory2`.

Finally, there is the `<view>` tag – with a lowercase `v` – which must have a `class` attribute (no prefix) with a value specifying the desired `View` class, abbreviated or full. This alternate format exists to allow for nested classes, as their names will contain the `$` character, which is not allowed in an XML tag name.

Comment: Easter egg! Hahaha, thank you. Your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**TextView**, **Buttons** etc are all these bundled by default but other widgets like **Constraint Layout** and etc they are not bundled by default they are part of support library. That's why you need give full package name. On the other hand, you can do the Same thing with widgets those are bundled by default as well(you can give complete package name for text view as well in XML). But there is no need to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not processing the XML programmatically to retrieve information including (complete) class name. So I want to confirm whether `android.widget` is the only default package prefix to add before the abbreviated forms like `TextView`.