# AsyncLayoutInflater that support factory 2

Tags: android, performance, view, factory

I am using AsyncLayoutInflater to increase performance when creating fragment view, and it is a great tool.

But the documentation said

> This inflater does not support setting a LayoutInflater.Factory nor LayoutInflater.Factory2. Similarly it does not support inflating layouts that contain fragments.

the problem starts here, all the attrs of (color & tint & background and background colors) of views will be ignored.

So I need to set them using code (java).

There is any way to avoid this work?? (many views need many customs colors and tints).

```
    AsyncLayoutInflater inflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(context);
    inflater.inflate(R.layour.second, bind.container, (view, resId, p) -> {
    
           bind.container.add(view);
           secondBind LayoutSecondBind.bind(view);

           //here I should set attr that AsyncLayoutInflater does not do
           //when inflating because of not supporting Factory / Factory2 

    });
```

XML Code (only part of real file)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchAutoCompleteTextLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/my75dp"
        android:hint="@string/search_product_hint"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/auto_complete_text_input_layout_color"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/icon_clear"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:endIconTint="@color/icon_tint_color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/searchAutoCompleteText"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my5dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_search"
            android:drawableTint="@color/icon_tint_color"
            android:dropDownHeight="@dimen/my150dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:lines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/my50dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/my50dp"


        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/searchAutoCompleteTextLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/searchAutoCompleteTextLayout"
        app:tint="@color/icon_tint_color" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/my75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_create_product"

        android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_scan_barcode"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/my25dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/my25dp"
        android:text="@string/create_product"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:drawableTint="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchAutoCompleteTextLayout" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sortText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_sort"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/product_sort_by"
        app:drawableTint="@color/icon_tint_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/sortBySpinner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/sortBySpinner" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sortBySpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/my35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/my10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sortText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview"
        />
```

The problem is: tint and color of view/backgrounds do not apply when inflate them, they are inflated with default values.

Note: I am using style for the spinner with background " rectangle with light red color" but after inflating its color becomes black.

Comment: "all the attrs of views will be ignored" – No, the `layout_*` attributes on the root `<View>` in the inflated layout will be ignored if there is no parent `ViewGroup` provided, but whether it's attached or not has no effect on that. It's not really clear what the issue is here.

Comment: @MikeM oh sorry I copied the wrong note :/,  I am talking about color + tint  + background color ... attrs that Factory(2) responsible to do.

Comment: The `Factory` interfaces don't have anything to do with those other attributes, either. It sounds like there might be some confusion as to what is actually happening, or how to interpret it. This'll probably be easier if you just provide a [mcve] that demonstrates and details the specific problem you're having.

Comment: @MikeM.  please check the XML code at the top, in summary, tint/color of view are ignored when the view is inflated( views/background does not appear with the color I set in XML file)

Comment: Oh, were you trying to say that those platform `View`s aren't being substituted with the library ones? Yeah, that would cause certain library attributes – ones with the `app` prefix – to not work. I'm not sure what kind of solution you're looking for, but you could just specify the necessary library `View`s yourself; e.g., change `<ImageView>` to `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>`. There are tables with all of the substitutions that would normally happen in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53863173).

Comment: @MikeM. oh, it works, switching view with "androidx.appcompat.widget. ". but the problem is  AsyncLayoutInflater does not support Factory(2) that is why views with old tag  "<ImageView>" didn't use the attrs, and after switch may be the views do it on their own "initView". do you have any documentation?, and big tnx you saved me :D.

Comment: "AsyncLayoutInflater does not support Factory(2) that is why views with old tag '<ImageView>' didn't use the attrs" – Kind of. I mean, that's why the standard appcompat mechanism isn't used there, but those factories aren't really "responsible" for any attributes; they just blindly pass them along. Anyhoo, no problem; glad it helped. I'm not sure what sort of documentation you're looking for, though.